# Remove <p> tag from wagtail's richtext field

Tags: wagtail

When you enter text within Wagtail's rich text editor in the Wagtail Admin without any styling (e.g bold, ul, italic), that text (when published) appears 'coated' or embedded in `<p>` tags. The text is also saved in the database with the `<p>` tags around the text content.

I would however like to access the text without having the `<p>` tags around. How can I do this please? From the research that I've made, it's quite clear that wagtail has made this the default behavior [and for obvious general use case reason], however, it would have been nice if it was also possible to access text without the bounding `<p>` tags.

I would like to access the content within the template so that it can be viewed from the frontend. Having a `<p>` tag goes a long way to hurt my CSS and working against wagtail's default design is like hunting in darkness

I've tried `StreamFields` and `StructBlocks`. The content still has the `<p>` tag. There seems to be no way to get rid of the `<p>` tags and access the required information.

Thanks and I hope a favourable reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specifically need rich text features then using a `RAWHtmlBlock` instead might fit the bill. For example:

```
body = StreamField([
    ('raw', RawHTMLBlock()),
])
```

will output:

```
<div class="block-raw">Your unmodified content</div>
```

If you need to remove only `<p>` while keeping the other markup tags, you could look at registering a `RewriteHandler` that would strip out the `<p>` tags for rendering. See
[Rich text internals](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/rich_text_internals.html)

Another crude way of doing the same would be to define a custom block template that strips out the `<p>`s before rendering {{ value }}.

```
# models.py
body = StreamField([
    ('bare', RichTextBlock(template='blocks/bare.html'))
])

# templates/blocks/bare.html
<script>
    /* Do something with {{ value }} */
    document.write(new_value);
</script>
```

Comment: Beware that `RawHTMLBlock` won't escape HTML so an editor could insert script tags and malicious code. The docs say to only use this if 100% trust the content editors:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#wagtail.core.blocks.RawHTMLBlock